# How to include XML comments files in Swagger in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I need Swagger generate API documentation include UI to test operations.

When use ASP.NET in my project, deps XML files are generated, everything is OK, look like this:

[image]

But when I use ASP.NET Core in my project, deps XML files are not generated. It just generates my project comments XML file, look like this:

[image]

And when I deploy my project to IIS, the project XML not in deploy files list.

Comment: did you remember to include <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile> in all of your .csproj files?  You also need to add each assembly inside .AddSwaggerGen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Enable "XML documentation file" checkbox **for each project** you depend on to generate their files on build. It could be done at project's properties Build tab.

To include all XML files on deploy, add this target to the published project's `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <DocFile Include="bin\*\*\*.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DocFile)" 
          DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

This will copy all XML files from `bin` folder and nested subfolders (like `bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\`) to `publish` dir. Of course you can customize that target.

Comment: You shouldn't need the custom script for copying XML files, simply checking the "XML documentation file" should be enough to do that. Just make sure you do that for _all_ Configurations, not just a specific one (e.g. `Debug`).

Comment: @SaebAmini You are both right.

Answer (score 51):

For **.Net Core 2 up to 8*** versions it's slightly different, for those who come across it using a newer version you would create your
`private void ConfigureSwagger(IServiceCollection services)` constructor, add the reference to swagger `services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.SwaggerDoc(/*populate with your info */);` then define a new parameter which will be the path for your swagger XML documentation:
`var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "YourApiName.xml"); c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);`.

It should look something like this:

```
private void ConfigureSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "YourApiName",
                Description = "Your Api Description.",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact
                    {Name = "Contact Title", Email = "contactemailaddress@domain.com", Url = ""}
            });
            var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "YourApiName.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
        });
    }
```

For this to work, you need to ensure that the build's Output has the documentation file checked (see red arrow) and the path set appropriately. I've noticed that *you can strip the pre-filled path* and just use `bin\YourApiName.xml`, just like below:

[image: Image showing how to enable XML documentation in Visual Studio 2017 IDE]

Update: If these changes aren't working as expected, please check the configuration. In the example, the config is set to Debug. If you're running from a different environment (env) you may need to check whether these setting apply to that env.

Update 2: Since the release of OpenAPI I thought I'd update my example (below) to show a more accurate reference to [this specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) which should follow something similar to:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
            {
                o.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "Your API Name",
                        Description = "Your API Description",
                        Version = "v1",
                        TermsOfService = null, 
                        Contact = new OpenApiContact 
                        {
                            // Check for optional parameters
                        },
                        License = new OpenApiLicense 
                        {
                            // Optional Example
                            // Name = "Proprietary",
                            // Url = new Uri("https://someURLToLicenseInfo.com")
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Update 3:
Thank you to comments from the community keeping this post updated within compatible versions.
*[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (AKA Swagger) is being removed in .NET 9.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54599)

Comment: Absolutely valid for .NET 7

Comment: Mostly valid for .NET 8 and VS 2022 as well, although the Output setting looks slightly different.

Answer (score 15):

I use this way to register XML file:

```
  foreach (var filePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)), "*.xml"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: worked a treat for me having controllers in multiple projects referenced by a single, main api project

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 11):

For .Net Core 3.1 and NuGet xml files I add this to project file:

```
<Project>

  <!-- Here is you other csproj code -->

  <Target Name="_ResolveCopyLocalNuGetPackageXmls" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' != '' and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

P.S. This is modified code from https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink#known-issues (2.8.3 version)

Comment: This actually works when building locally. Do note that if you build in a Docker context you might have to add `ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=none` to get the xml files included.

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft themselves have documentation for this question available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments), I found it quite helpful.

In short, the following changes are required:

`Startup.cs, ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
});
```

`{project_name}.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml) suggests using a `DocumentationFile` tag in your csproj file.

Just make sure you have the correct build for your deployment (Release/Debug):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\APIProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I just used this in practice (with the tweaks below) and it works well:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

For .Net 7, in your project file, add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your Program.cs file, add:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In .net core 3.1,Please follow the below steps:

Go to Startup.cs Page and add the below code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { 
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo 
                {
                    Title="Book Store API",
                    Version="v1",
                    Description="This is an educational site"
                });
                var xfile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xpath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,xfile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xpath);
            });
            
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

After that go to Properties of the project and click on the XML Documentation File option and save it.
[image]